# Failed installing msodbcsql on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, unixodbc

I want to try the SQL server on Linux, and I installed unixODBC version 2.3.1 via command line

and when I execute this command in msodbcsql-13.0.0.0

```
./install.sh install --force
```

I got this result

```
...
Checking for 64 bit Linux compatible OS...................................... OK
Checking required libs are installed ........................................ OK
unixODBC utilities (odbc_config and odbcinst) installed ..................... OK
unixODBC Driver Manager version 2.3.1 installed ......................... FAILED
unixODBC Driver Manager configuration correct ...................... NOT CHECKED
Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server already installed .......... NOT CHECKED
Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server files copied ........................ OK
Symbolic links for bcp and sqlcmd created ................................... OK
Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server registered ................... INSTALLED

Install log created at /tmp/msodbcsql.10441.22976.30076/install.log.

One or more steps may have an *. See README for more information regarding
these steps.
```

Is there's a suggestion what should I do? I've brosing all the time but i can't solve this.

Comment: which user did you use to install it? See http://lifeofageekadmin.com/install-microsoft-sql-drivers-unixodbc-2-3-0-rhel-6-64-bit/

Comment: i'm using root @fedorqui